# Brother QL 570 will not print

Tags: usb, 15.10, printing, cups-lpd

I've set up my Brother QL 570 label printer, installed all the drivers using terminal and verified that they've been installed correctly using the 'dpkg -l  | grep Brother' command.

I've tried printing with Libre Office Writer and gLabels but I'm not getting anywhere. With gLabels, I can select exactly the label type that I have installed in the printer so there shouldn't be any issues with printing outside of margins etc, which may of prevented printing.

The printer appears on System Settings okay. The status is at Idle until when I try to print a test page then it displays 'Processing - Sending data to printer' for a second or so then it changes to 'Idle - 'Sending data to printer' and then remains with that status with no further activity. No test page is produced from doing this.

Do I need to change any settings elsewhere perhaps? This is the the last thing that is holding me back from switching fully from Windows to Ubuntu, something I'm very keen to do, and I can't wait to get this working! :)

Thanks in advance! :)

Paul.

Comment: Could you please post screenshots of the printer properties? Especially the first two sections (*Settings* and *Policies*).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution to this problem in the German Ubuntu forum. It is quite simple:

Install the package lib32stdc++6 and you're good to go.

`sudo apt get install lib32stdc++6`

One addition: to make use of custom sized labels, have a look at 
`brpapertoollpr_ql570`, which can add media size definitions to your printer configuration.

Regards

Dirk