# Brother QL-570 label printer won't work since I upgraded to 16.04

Tags: drivers, brother

I had this printer working fine under 12.04 using ubuntu recomended QL-500 foomatic driver.  Since I upgraded to 16.04 it does not work anymore.  When I send the print job, the led starts flashing red, and nothing prints.  This is true with Brother drivers that I have tried as well.

I have tried this

[brother ql570 labelprinter driver does not work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831689/brother-ql570-labelprinter-driver-does-not-work)

but nothing changes - my 32bit libraries are the latest available.

I have also tried this:

[Brother QL 570 will not print](https://askubuntu.com/questions/749854/brother-ql-570-will-not-print)

again no joy.  However I have some error messages relating to virtualbox which I have installed.

Thank you for any help - I need my labels to deliver my bread to shops tomorrow.....

Comment: the foomatic driver you are using is the open-source one; Brother supply a driver your printer: if you go here http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_esp.html#QL-570 and download and install first the lpr and then the cupswrapper driver; the command seems to be `dpkg  -i  --force-all  (lpr-drivername)` if you use the terminal; then `dpkg  -i  --force-all  (cupswrapper-drivername)` so let us know how it goes; obviously substitute the correct name ..  pob lwc  .. best delete the existing icon that does not work, from the PRINTERS folder?

Comment: I tried deleting the existing icon and installing the brother pilots but still have flashing red light.  dwi'm y  dallt o gwbwl be ddiawl sy'n bod!

Comment: I tried deleting the exisint icon and installing the Brother pilots, but still get falshing red light - dwi'm yn gwbod be ddiawl sy'n bod!

Comment: the FAQ on the QL series is all very old http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_esp.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&redirect=on so sorry: no further suggestions but this wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingPrintingProblems talks of a CUPS error log that you can tweak so it records all; if it posts errors, you could post them here; or the Ubuntu Forum https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=332